# Creating vacuum in a rubber hose by replacing air with helium which escapes through osmosis?

Tags: pressure, vacuum

Yesterday I heard this: suppose you have a rubber hose, in which you inject helium, which replaces the air which was there before. Now, because there is no helium in air, so the partial pressure is zero there, the helium escapes through the rubber into the surrounding air and creates vacuum in the hose (insofar it is possible in a rubber hose, effectively you'll get substantially lower pressure than before). Is this correct? If so, se can create vacuum using a solid membrane, which permits the gas (that we used to replace the air inside) to escape to the outside world, where its partial pressure was zero/low?

Comment: (+1) It works the other way, as well: see the [exploding tennis balls](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/135438/79678)!